# Invoke-VMScript - PowerCli - compatibility

Tags: bash, powershell, powercli

I wonder what guest OS are compatible to the `invoke-VMScript` cmdlet. The reason I'm asking: I plan to include VMWare in my (automated) test environment. What I read so far:

- Windows Server 2008
- Windows Server 2012
- A Fedora-Version

I would like to know, what windows and linux guest you have experience with and (if appliable) what languages are invokeable. E.g. CMD at windows, or maybe Bash or Powershell at Linux.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FInvoke-VMScript.html) powershell bat(cmd) and bash are all supported, I don't have a linux machine handy to confirm but based on [this link](https://technodrone.blogspot.com/2013/01/invoke-vmscript-failed-and-how-i-was.html) it looks like you can run powershell on Linux VM's as long as .Net and Powershell have been installed and the machine has been rebooted since this install.  Beyond that depending on the VM config you can use any of those methods to create and launch scripts that target just about any language by building them as strings inside of the script that is delivered, writing them to a temp file and then launching the correct interpreter and calling the newly created file. note that there seem to be a bunch of edge-cases here so you may want to review the requirements [here](http://www.lucd.info/2012/01/01/will-invoke-vmscript-work/)